# JQRangeSlider Customized bounds not getting set

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins

I have a JSON Object in the following format:

```
  var dataset =  
  [
  {
    "date_hour": "2014-04-30T18:30:00Z",
    "mv": "OTHERS",
    "time_period": "Daily",
    "platform": "MWEB"
  },
  {
    "date_hour": "2014-04-30T18:30:00Z",
    "mv": "SEO",
    "time_period": "Daily",
    "platform": "CORESITE"
  },
  {
    "date_hour": "2014-04-30T18:30:00Z",
    "mv": "EMAIL",
    "time_period": "Hourly",
    "platform": "MWEB"
  }]
```

I have to create a date-time slider for this data.I am using JQRangeSlider for this purpose.Here is the code snippet:

```
  var min = dataset[0].date_hour
  var max = dataset[dataset.length - 1].date_hour;
  $("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
      bounds: {min: "min",max: "max"}
      });
```

My actual dataset is huge and is sorted,too.So,min and max has the minimum and maximum timestamp value stored in them.However,the bounds for the slider are not getting set.Is is wrong to pass variables like this or there is some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget jQRangeSlider only accepts bounds as date objects. The JSON data you're retreiving contains date values in strings.

Secondly, in you example, the bounds object receives "min" and "max" strings as bounds. I suppose there is a typo here.

1. Parse date values to create javascript `Date` objects
2. Set bounds option with these dates

My suggestion:

```
// Be sure not to change your date format
var min = new Date(dataset[0].date_hour),
    max = new Date(dataset[dataset.length - 1].date_hour);

$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
  bounds: {min: min, max: max}
  });
```

Comment: Can you have a look at this?  link[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031156/making-scale-of-jqrangeslider-hourly]