# Making scale of jQRangeSlider hourly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jQRangeSlider for my dashboard.I am trying to use the scale option that the widget provides using the snippet given in the documentation.However, my Date slider has a range of 14 days.What I want is that I should have a ruler marked with hours of a day rather than the month shown in the documentation at

link[[http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html#scalesOption]](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html#scalesOption%5d)

I am trying to do this using the following snippet:

```
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
bounds: {"min": min2,"max":max2},
      range:{
          min: {hours: 1}},
          scales: [{
           first: function(value){ return value; },
           end: function(value) {return value; },
           next: function(value){
           var next = new Date(value);
           return new Date(next.setHours(value.getHours() + 1));
      },
      label: function(value){
        return months[value.getHours()];
      },
      format: function(tickContainer, tickStart, tickEnd){
        tickContainer.addClass("myCustomClass");
      }
    }]
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be good, except for the `label` option and some syntax errors, you can try this code:

```
var min2 = new Date("2014-01-01"),
    max2 = new Date("2014-01-02");

function addZero(val) {
    if (val < 10) {
        return "0" + val;
    }

    return val;
}

$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    bounds: {
        "min": min2,
        "max": max2
    },
    range: {
        min: {
            hours: 1
        }
    },
    scales: [{
        first: function (value) {
            return value;
        },
        end: function (value) {
            return value;
        },
        next: function (value) {
            var next = new Date(value);
            return new Date(next.setHours(value.getHours() + 1));

        },
        label: function (value) {
            return value.getHours();
        },
        format: function (tickContainer, tickStart, tickEnd) {
            tickContainer.addClass("myCustomClass");
        }
    }],
    formatter: function (val) {
        var h = val.getHours(),
            m = val.getMinutes();

        return addZero(h) + ':' + addZero(m);
    },
    defaultValues: {
        min: new Date("2014-01-01T05:00:00Z"),
        max: new Date("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z")
    }
});
```

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/ghusse/LJrYf/1/

Comment: Awesome.!!.Working fine now.!!.Just that for my 14 days range the slider looks quite crowded.Still,great help.!!.Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to show the date along with the time in the formatter.If yes, how?

Comment: Customize the formatter calkback to make it return what you want to display

Comment: Done.!!.Can I get data.values.min or data.values.max from the slider even when the slider is not moved,something like userValuesUnchanged???

Comment: You can use the method named values. Take a look at the documentation on this method to see how to use it.

Comment: hey ghusse, I want to change the 'blue' color of the slider to some other color that suits my dashboard. Hoaw can that be done??

Comment: Just customize the css

Comment: this one: https://github.com/ghusse/jQRangeSlider/blob/master/css/iThing.css#L152

Comment: @ ghusse.. How do I ensure that the slider movement event gets called once.I am facing a problem which is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759135/jquery-ajax-called-twice-from-uservalueschanged-in-daterangeslider and a solution of this kind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866972/jquery-ajax-request-is-being-sent-twice might help but I don't know how to go about it for the 'UserValuesChanged' event in the dateRangeSlider

Comment: You have an example here: http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/events.html#userValuesChangedEvent what do you need exactly?