# jQuery.ajax called twice from userValuesChanged in dateRangeSlider

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jQDateRangeSlider to trigger a jQuery.ajax call.There are two ways in which the slider can be moved.

1. By moving the ends of the slider individually
2. By moving the entire highlighted block from one place to other

In case of 1, my code works fine, but in case 2, the 'userValuesChanged' gets invoked two or four times.Is this some bug with the widget or am I doing something wrong here? This is how my code looks?

```
function init() {
    var tp = $('tp').value;
    if (tp == 'Daily') {
        dataFile1 = "http://localhost:8080/composite2/Composite/datejson";

        d3.json(dataFile1, function (error, data) {
            if (data) dataset1 = data;
            var min = dataset1[0].a;
            var jugad = dataset1[0].c;
            jugad2 = new Date(jugad);
            var min2 = new Date(min);
            var max = dataset1[dataset1.length - 1].b;
            var max2 = new Date(max);

            function addZero(val) {
                if (val < 10) {
                    return "0" + val;
                }
                return val;
            }
            var s = $j("#slider").dateRangeSlider({

                bounds: {
                    "min": min2,
                    "max": max2
                },
                range: {
                    min: {
                        hours: 25
                    },
                    max: {
                        days: 7
                    },
                },
                formatter: function (val) {
                    var m = moment(val);
                    return m.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:00:00 ");
                },
                defaultValues: {
                    min: min2,
                    max: max2
                }
            });
            x = jugad2;
            x.setMinutes(0);
            x.setSeconds(0);
            z = x.getFullYear() + '-' + (x.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + x.getDate() + ' ' + x.getHours() + ':' + '00' + ':' + '00';
            var y = (s.dateRangeSlider("values").max);
            y.setMinutes(0);
            y.setSeconds(0);
            b = y.getFullYear() + '-' + (y.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + y.getDate() + ' ' + y.getHours() + ':' + '00' + ':' + '00'
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'metric=' + $('metric').value + '&tp=' + $('tp').value + '&date_hour=' + z + '&date_hour=' + b,
                url: '/composite2/Composite/ajaxGetMv',
                success: function (data, textStatus) {
                    loadData(data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
            });

            $j('#slider').on("userValuesChanged", function (e, data) {
                var x = data.values.min;
                x.setMinutes(0);
                x.setSeconds(0);
                z = x.getFullYear() + '-' + (x.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + x.getDate() + ' ' + x.getHours() + ':' + '00' + ':' + '00';
                var last = data.values.max;
                last.setMinutes(0);
                last.setSeconds(0);
                b = last.getFullYear() + '-' + (last.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + last.getDate() + ' ' + last.getHours() + ':' + '00' + ':' + '00';
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'metric=' + $('metric').value + '&tp=' + $('tp').value + '&date_hour=' + z + '&date_hour=' + b,
                    url: '/composite2/Composite/ajaxGetMv',
                    success: function (data, textStatus) {
                        loadData(data);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
                });
            })
        });
    } //end of Daily Slider
} //end of init()
```

**UPDATE**

init() is being called from function decide.

```
function decide()
{
var tp = $('tp').value;
if (tp == 'Daily')
{

  init();
}
 else
 {

  init1();
 }
}
```

This function decide() is being called on the onchange of a dropdown 'tp'

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It will make it much easier for you and others to read.

Comment: You could've removed the unwanted `console.log()`'s instead of dumping the whole code as it is...

Comment: Sorry, removed it.! Thanks for pointing out.!

Comment: how are you calling `init()` ?

Comment: try using  $j('#slider').one("userValuesChanged" instead of  $j('#slider').on

Comment: Works, but after one movement over the slider, it stops working.No matter how you move the slider the uservalues changed block doesn't get invoked from the second movement onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having to guess a bit here as you don't say what versions of the libraries you're using. However I tested the plugin in jsFiddle and it works fine, so I assume that you're doing repeated calls to `init` which are binding extra handlers to the event. You say:

> This function `decide()` is being called on the onchange of a dropdown `tp`

This means that whenever that dropdown changes `init` is called again and the handler is added **again** to that event. You can see this happening here in my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/2ry320vy/), counts are normal until you click the button to call `init()` again. There are a few ways round this, see the comments in the fiddle as well.

**Option 1** -- Simple but not really elegant.

Just destroy the slider at the start of the init() routine:

```
function init() {      
    $j("#slider").dateRangeSlider("destroy");
```

This doesn't throw an error if the slider hasn't been initialized (looks like the plugin has some sanity checking) but it may cause a visual glitch on some browsers.

**Option 2** -- A bit better

Use a global variable to keep a note of if you've created the event

```
var is_init = false;
function init() { 

    // ... other code ... 

    if (!is_init) 
    {
        $j('#slider').on("userValuesChanged", function (e, data) {
            // ... handler code ... 
        });
        is_init = true;
    } 
}
```

There are a few other ways to use the 'global variable' idea, including faking static function variables but this is the simple way and it may work since you have two init routines.

**Option 3** -- Probably my choice

Your `init()` function is really a (re)init since it can be called more than once. You only want to bind the handler once so you can just do it *outside* the init function (or inside a different function that's only called once). You can do this before calling init, just after page load. This works it just registers an event handler, it doesn't care that at that point that element can't generate the event, it'll handle it just fine later. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/pc4xk2y1/) for that.

It really sounds like you want an `init` function somewhere that's called once (not tied to an element) and a `reinit` function tied to the dropdown that just changes the values but doesn't rebind the event. I don't see anything in your event handler that changes depending on the different settings but if there is you'll probably have to go with Option 1.

There are some other options (unbind the event handler, detect if there's already a handler bound) but they may run into more trouble if other handlers are also bound to that event.

And this may not be the root cause of your problem, but I hope the fiddles help you in any case.